# Nested divs, each div has image, show the images side-by-side

Tags: html, css

Using nested divs, each div has a background image, I want the images side-by-side

I am trying to put stars side-by-side.
here is my html & css code

```
<body>
  <div class="rate-stars">

    <div class"star" id="s5"><pre> </pre>
        <div class"star" id="s4"><pre> </pre>
            <div class"star" id="s3"><pre> </pre>
                <div class"star" id="s2"><pre> </pre>
                    <div class"star" id="s1"><pre> </pre>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
       </div>

</body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
.star
{
background-image: url("star-off.png");
float: left;
border: 0px;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: why are you not closing the divs after the pre tag?

Comment: @Shail I want them nested.

Comment: why are you putting pre tags?

Comment: and where you place images?

Comment: @Ankit images are not loading at all, so i tried using pre tags. Images are in the same dir as html file.

Comment: @rao Are you using sprites ?

Comment: @Shail No, I will be using it later when this image works.

Comment: One advise Use Span in place of pre tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wNVBS/)

Your first problem is you're missing the `=` in all of your class assignments:

```
 <div class"star"
          ^ missing =
```

With those fixed, this CSS will do it:

```
.star
{
    background-image: url("star-off.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left:25px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following :

HTML  can written as :

```
<div id="rate-stars">

<img id="star1" src="img/star1.png">
    <img id="star2" src="img/star2.png">

</div>
```

Css :

```
    #star1 {
      left: 20px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 100px;
     }
    #star2 {
      left: 60px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 100px;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this css

```
.star
{
background-image: url("star-off.png") no-repeat top left;
border: 0px;
padding-left: 20px;
height: 20px;
margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Pehaps but he didn't mentioned anywhere :), if needed to make rating functionality he better to have sibbling divs for stars instead of nesting them.

Comment: Heyy, I am looking like commenting to myself, why to post comment if going to delete it.